# LINQ join in Best way without multiple from clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ. It's my Linq Query Here

```
var users = from UserTbl in entity.User
            from grpTbl in entity.Group
            from role in entity.Role
            where grpTbl.groupID == UserTbl.groupID&& UserTbl.userID==role.userID 
            select new Contract.User()
            {
                UserId = UserTbl.userID,
                UserName = UserTbl.userName,
                FirstName = UserTbl.firstName,
                LastName = UserTbl.lastName,
                GroupId = grpTbl.groupID,
                GroupName =grpTbl.groupName,
                DesignationID = role.roleID    
            };
```

How can I write this query in the best way?

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: Have you executed this query, or just only written?
grpTbl.groupID == groupId is not complete, you need to include a reference of UserTbl as well.

Comment: @ShahidAzim, presumably those 2 are references declared outside of the query. Only the query has been provided here. Looks fine to me too.

Comment: @Gulshan, avoid putting Hi/Bye/Thanks headers/footers in question text. Just make sure you have put enough information regarding your question and stick to the point.

Comment: @ShahidAzim - There is a reference to `UserTbl` in the query.

Comment: @Jaymz totally agree, query seems to be fine to me as well. @Gulshan Why don't you use LINQPad, it is pretty decent application to test LINQ queries.

Comment: @ShaidAzim i does n't need to check syntax.I need to know the way i written query is good or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is pretty fine. but I prefer `joins` because they make possible to remove "matching" expressions out of `where` clause, so that only "true" filtering remains there.

```
var users = from UserTbl in entity.User
            join grpTbl in entity.Group on grpTbl.groupID equals groupId            
            join role in entity.Role on UserTbl.userID equals role.userID 
            select new Contract.User()
            {
                UserId = UserTbl.userID,
                UserName = UserTbl.userName,
                FirstName = UserTbl.firstName,
                LastName = UserTbl.lastName,
                GroupId = grpTbl.groupID,
                GroupName =grpTbl.groupName,
                DesignationID = role.roleID    
            };
```

Comment: I'd put 'on' clauses on new line. looks more cleaner to me that way.